# short links without htaccess how?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hey my friends i am a noob in htaccess and i need you help :)

Thats my htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule pro/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?site=$1&cat=$2
RewriteRule go/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?site=$1&cat=$2
RewriteRule goto/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?site=$1&cat=$2
RewriteRule buying/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?site=$1&cat=$2
RewriteRule pay index.php?site=pay
RewriteRule delivery index.php?site=delivery
RewriteRule faq index.php?site=faq
RewriteRule contact index.php?site=contact
RewriteRule replace index.php?site=replace
```

My current produkt links are :

```
http://localhost/pro/id/keys
http://localhost/pro/id/voucher
http://localhost/pro/id/tools
```

Is it possible to make my links to ?:

```
http://localhost/keys.exe
http://localhost/voucher.exe
http://localhost/tools.exe
Or without .exe at the end ?
```

Sry for my bad englisch :S I hope anyone from you guys can help me by my problem :(

A user said me that :
replace this rule:

```
RewriteRule pro/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?site=$1&cat=$2

with

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.exe$ /index.php?site=id&cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it not work

Comment: This question is not realy PHP related. Your script handling the requests is PHP but the question is purely about .htaccess. Is that a correct assumption?
With that another crucial question came up for me. What happens to the ID? In the produkt links you include the product id. In the short-urls you do not need them?